# wpf bing map application with heat map?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing, heatmap

i am trying to integrate bing map with heat map feature into my wpf desktop application, is there any API to do this? i searched the microsoft website and i can only found API for developing a map apps, which i think is different from what i want... any idea where should i start??

update: i think microsoft only provide the bing API for silverlight, and i found this one for WPF, but i dont know how to generate the heat map on this... can anyone point me to somewhere?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/BingMapsWebServiceExample.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that 3rd party component from Telerik would be useful? If you can afford it, it will save you a lot of time.

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx

It uses Bing maps and supports heat maps.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS also offers a more flexible WPF control with heat maps, [check the dev tools here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#//017000000095000000)